# I want to pass data to popup dialogFragment

Tags: kotlin

in kotlin … I want to pass data to a custom popup window which extends dialogFragment so  anyone here knows how can I pass data  to  such a fragment  ?.
I have error every time I pass data to the constructor.
Please help.

pass data to the constructor

```
class PopUpClass : DialogFragment() {



    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        var v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.poplayout,container,false 

        return v
    }
//tried to pass the data in the constructor and then handle it but did not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it in Kotlin, first declare a companion object with instance of your fragment class

```
companion object {
@JvmStatic //This can be avoided if you are in a complete Kotlin project
fun newInstance(content: String): PopUpClass {
  val args = Bundle()
  args.putString("content", content)
  val fragment = PopUpClass()
  fragment.arguments = args
  return fragment
 }
}
```

Inside onCreate() or onViewCreated() of your fragment you can receive the data like this

```
val dataPassed: String? = arguments?.getString("content")
```

Call the newInstance instead of constructor from your parent activity or fragment

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [dialog fragment documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment).

You need to create a function getInstance that passes your parameters through a bundle to the fragment. Like this:

```
static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int num) { 
 MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment(); // Supply num input as an argument. 
 Bundle args = new Bundle(); 
 args.putInt("num", num); 
 f.setArguments(args); 
 return f;
}
```